# I want to know how to remove this code from a wordpress page or the template all together. <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="ihf-board-disclaimers">

Tags: css

When I enter a shortcode, there is some hidden css that comes up from the entering of the shortcode. I have placed the disclaimer in another section on the website, and don't need it in the place it comes up.

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="ihf-board-disclaimers">
    <!----><div _ngcontent-c2="">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!----><p _ngcontent-c2="">(the text is here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your custom css

```
.ihf-board-disclaimers{
  display:none !important;
}
```

You can use jQuery to hide it at document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ihf-board-disclaimers').css('display', 'none');
});
```